# How do I use TestPropertyProvider and inject RxHttpClient with Micronaut using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

*Note - I'm a Java+Spring guy trying out Kotlin+Micronaut.*

I'm trying to use the `TestPropertyProvider` to set properties after my embedded service starts.
It works ok, as long as there are no constructor parameters in my test class.

I can add the `RxHttpClient` as a constructor parameter and it gets injected fine.

But, I'd like to inject the `RxHttpClient` from Micronaut and also implement `TestPropertyProvider`.
I tried adding `@Inject` to the `RxHttpClient` but get the error `This annotation is not applicable to target 'local variable'` [because the test body is a lambda passed to the superclass]

Without the `@Inject` I get the error `lateinit property client has not been initialized`

My base class has the `TestPropertyProvider` implementation .

```
abstract class ZeebeSpecification(body: AbstractStringSpec.() -> Unit): StringSpec(body), TestPropertyProvider {
    override fun getProperties(): MutableMap<String, String> {
        return mutableMapOf("orchestrator.management.client.brokerContactPoint" to IntegrationTestHarness.instance.getBroker())
    }
}
```

---

`TestPropertyProvider` works, but `RxHttpClient` not injected

```
@MicronautTest
class ZeebeBroker1Test() : ZeebeSpecification({

    @Client("/") lateinit var client: RxHttpClient;

    ...tests

}) {}
```

---

`RxHttpClient` injected, but `TestPropertyProvider` not evaluated

```
@MicronautTest
class ZeebeBroker1Test(@Client("/" val client: RxHttpClient) : ZeebeSpecification({


    ...tests

}) {}
```

---

I removed the base class from the equation and made my test directly implement the `TestPropertyProvider` but it still fails.

```
@MicronautTest
class ZeebeBroker1Test(@Client("/") var client: HttpClient) : BehaviorSpec(), TestPropertyProvider {

    init {
        ...tests
    }
    private fun getBroker(): String {
        return IntegrationTestHarness.instance.getBroker()
    }
    override fun getProperties(): MutableMap<String, String> {
        return mutableMapOf("orchestrator.management.client.brokerContactPoint" to getBroker())
    }
}
```

Seems like it's the same issue as this, but I'm already using v1.1.2
https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-test/issues/82

If I tried to use `@Inject @Client("/") client: RxHttpClient` it would throw the error `message: Missing bean argument [LoadBalancer loadBalancer] for type: io.micronaut.http.client.DefaultHttpClient. Required arguments: LoadBalancer`

How do I use both `TestPropertyProvider` and injected `RxHttpClient`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by moving the body of the spec into the `init`, and injecting the `RxHttpClient` as a field.

```
@MicronautTest
class ZeebeBroker1Test() : ZeebeSpecification() {

    @Inject @field:Client("/") lateinit var client: RxHttpClient

    private val log: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ZeebeBroker1Test::class.java)

    init {
        "test case 1" {
            ...
        }

        "test case 2" {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

And I let the base class implement the `TestPropertyProvider` interface .

```
abstract class ZeebeSpecification(): StringSpec(), TestPropertyProvider {

    open fun getBroker(): String {
        return IntegrationTestHarness.instance.getBroker()
    }

    override fun getProperties(): MutableMap<String, String> {
        return mutableMapOf("orchestrator.management.client.brokerContactPoint" to getBroker())
    }
}
```

Comment: 3.5 years later and this was still helpful, thanks for posting your findings.

FYI I eventually came across this detail in the [micronaut-test docs on kotest](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/index.html#kotest5).